# "Variable expected" error when calling getValue on a mutable map with a nullable type

Tags: kotlin, types, maps, nullable

I'm having a problem with altering the value of a mutable map. I assume it's something to do with nullable types, but I'm not sure. The code producing the error is below:

```
fun countHexadecimalNumbers(codes: List<String>): Map<Int, Int> {
  val map = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
  for (s in codes) {
    val num = s.toIntOrNull(16)
    if (num != null) {
      if (num !in map.keys) {
        map[num] = 0
      }
      map.getValue(num) += 1 %<--This line causes the issue
    }
  }
  return map
```

When I try and build the code I get this error:

```
Nullable Types\Exercise 3\src\Task.kt: (13, 11): Variable expected
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `map.getValue(num) += 1` is not allowed because the `+=` operator is only defined in 2 cases:

1. a [plusAssign()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#augmented-assignments) operator is defined on the left operand's type (not the case for `Int`)
2. a [plus()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#arithmetic-operators) operator is defined on the left operand's type AND the left operand is a *variable*. In this case `+=` reassigns the variable on the left with `oldValue.plus(the right operand)`.

The compiler tries to consider case #2 here because `Int.plus(Int)` is defined, but the left operand is not a variable so it fails with the error message you mentioned.
You can't write this for the same reasons you can't write `map.getValue(num) = 42`.

The correct way of mutating a value in a map is either via the [set](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator) operator (like you did earlier with the syntax sugar `map[num] = 0`), or via other mutating functions like [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

In your case, `merge` is nice because it can remove the special case altogether (it's only available on the JVM target though):

```kotlin
val map = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
for (s in codes) {
    val num = s.toIntOrNull(16)
    if (num != null) {
        map.merge(num, 1, Int::plus)
    }
}
```

Here is what this `merge` does:

- if the key doesn't exist in the map, it just sets the value given as second argument (the value 1)
- if the key already exists, then a new value is computed using the function given as 3rd argument (just a sum). That function is called with the old value and the 2nd argument (the value 1) as inputs, and should return the new value to assign, so in this case `old + 1`.

Note that, in your case, the whole loop can be simplified this way:

```kotlin
fun countHexadecimalNumbers(codes: List<String>): Map<Int, Int> {
    return codes.mapNotNull { it.toIntOrNull(16) }.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
}
```

Comment: So when I call getValue, what exactly is returned? I assumed it was a reference to the data in the map.

Comment: @Connor it returns the value associated with the key. If this value is of a primitive type, you cannot change it. If the value is a reference type, you cannot change the reference either (so you can't change which object the key is associated to), but you can change the contents of the object if it has mutable fields. You can draw a parallel with function parameters: you can do as much to `getValue`'s result as what you can do to function parameters from inside a function's body.